# combining launch files doesn't give same behavior: order / timing of ik solver

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ik, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to launch nodes in one combined launch file.

If I launch nodes separately using the two files below, calls to the IK services work fine  (i.e. call the second node's service ik_trajectory, which uses the first node's ik solver) :

`ik_solver.launch`:

```
<launch>  
  <include file="$(find pr2_arm_navigation_kinematics)/launch/pr2_ik_rarm_node.launch"/>  
</launch>
```

`cartesian_ik_trajectory.launch`:

```
<launch>  
  <node pkg="ik_trajectory" type="ik_trajectory" name="ik_trajectory"/>  
</launch>
```

The IK also works if I run the first launch file and use "rosrun ik_trajectory ik_trajectory" in place of the second launch file.

However, if I combine the two commands in one launch file, the service calls fail even though the input / starting arm state for IK is the same:

`combined.launch`:

```
<launch>  
   <include file="$(find pr2_arm_navigation_kinematics)/launch/pr2_ik_rarm_node.launch"/>   
   <node pkg="ik_trajectory" type="ik_trajectory" name="ik_trajectory"/>   
</launch>
```

The node in the second launch file was written by someone else, so I'm trying to look into those details.  However, I don't understand why the behavior should be different.  Is there an ordering or timing issue with the IK solver?  I can even launch the separate launch files in reverse order without problem.  It's only when I combine the commands in one launch file that the service fails.

Note that there's no failure when I actually run the launch files, only when I call the service provided by the second ik_trajectory node.  I checked rosservice list to see that the same services are available in either case.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10567/combining-launch-files-doesn%27t-give-same-behavior:-order-/-timing-of-ik-solver/) by [elsey](https://answers.ros.org/users/347/elsey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-07-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-07-11**:
nothing wrong :) very minor cosmetic update, I made the launch xml blocks into formatted syntax-colored quotations (by indenting 4 white spaces in front).

**Comment by [elsey](https://answers.ros.org/users/347/elsey/) on 2011-07-11**:
@hsu, What was updated by you about my posting?  Was there something wrong about my formatting?  I'd like to know for the next time I post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no guaranteed ordering in roslaunch. All programs should behave nicely to work.

I'm assuming your second program just calls a service? What probably happens is that the service call is done before the service is up.
To fix that you should wait until a service becomes available in the other program and then go into the processing part.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2